# Google Chrome javascript debugger: object inspect not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I have been using Chrome to debug node.js code with node-inspector for a while now. However, lately I started having an issue with the debugger and I don't know why.

When I try to inspect an object, instead of expanding it and show me it's property it tries to modify its value, which is "Object".
The only way I found to see the value is to type in the console "obj.property".

I have this problem in the console as well when objects are printed.

In the image below, you can see that I can expand the Local and Global scope, but not any of the red marked variables. Also, in the console I can expand bar, but not bar.foo. It feels like anything marked with the format "variableName: Type" cannot be expanded.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently my node-inspector was out of date (though not showing when typing npm outdated -g)

I updated it manually and it fixes the problem